# Run the JButton when a KeyEvent has been pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, keyevent

```
frame.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key typed = " + e.getKeyChar());
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                //My JButton is called b1, how do i make it run here when enter is pressed?
            System.out.println("ENTER");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: 1) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`. 2) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it all i had to do is add

b1.doClick();

in my if statement